# Execute JS code right after QML Application start

Tags: qt, qml

I've got an ApplicationWindow in my QML-Application.
I'd like to execute a bit of Javascript-code right after loading it but don't find a handler (like onLoaded) to do so.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The handler you're looking for is [Component.onCompleted](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal).  Here's a simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent

        // First paint a red rectangle
        color: "red"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Make it blue when we load
        rect.color = "blue"
    }
}
```